# using html tags in resource bundle

Tags: java

I try to put a message from a resource bundle which contains html tags like:

```
application.portal.action.help=test <a href\="https://google.ro" target\="_blank">the opt in conditions</a>
```

in a jsf outputLabel:

```
<h:outputLabel id="test" value="#{myupmessages['application.portal.action.help']}"></h:outputLabel>
```

Well...the text is rendered as a plain text iso of rendering the link.

Do you have any ideea ..why?

Thanks.

Comment: The properties can be used to contain translations, but it's a really bad idea to put in there content that is not plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found:

I do need to add:

```
escape="false"
```

to the outputLabel control :)